# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2010-12-10 17:18:3600

Tags: android, parsing, datetime

i'm getting this exception when i try to parse a date that i get from a SQL database, the date is a datetime on the sql and i recive it as a String with JSON, and seeing the excepcion i think that the string i recived is like this:`2010-12-10 17:18:3600`

this is the exception i get:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2010-12-10 17:18:3600
```

i use the next code to parse the date (i get it from google) but it gets the exception

How can i modify this code to get the parse working???? please guive me the answer with code, date parsing and using of simpledateformat it's very hard for me

```
 public void setPositiontime(String positiondate) 
     { 
            SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
            // pad the date if necessary
            while (!positiondate.endsWith("00")){
             positiondate += "0";
            }
            try {
                this.positiondate = FORMATTER.parse(positiondate.trim());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

i get the error on this line:  `this.positiondate = FORMATTER.parse(positiondate.trim());`

Comment: How is "17:18:3600" supposed to be understood? Is this a standard format?

Comment: 36 are the seconds, and the next 00 are added by the while, but i dont know why, that code is copyed from google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
    SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS");
It is simply a representation of what each digit in the format means so its:
Years-months-date hour:min:milli

Comment: but i dont want to use that format.... i need to use this exact format: d MMM yyyy HH:mm

Comment: i have to use it, it's a requirement of the app, to use that exact format, then your solution is not valid for me :(

Comment: But you can't parse the date 2010-12-10 17:18:3600 using the parser "d MMM yyyy HH:mm" one of them will have to change.

Comment: why i can't ?? i read on google that SympleDateFormat are for give a date the format you want :S

Comment: Ok, so the string I gave you is for parsing the input, after that you can print it again in another format is that what you want to do?

Comment: mmmm maybe it can works, can i reparse it to the format i need?

Comment: If you first manage to parse it to a date you can then use a simple date format to print it any way you want:

SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
String out = FORMATTER2.format(this.positiondate);